# How to set the variable type in PHP

Tags: php, types, casting, mysqli

I created a class `MySQLConnector` with the field `connection`. I have a connect function that can set the `$this->connection` variable:

```
public function connect($host, $user, $password, $database)
{
    $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);

    if(!$mysqli->connect_errno)
        $this->connection = $mysqli;
}
```

The problem is: `$this->connection` isn't a `mysqli` type. It doesn't have a type. How can I cast or set the type correctly? I want to use `$this->connection->query()`. In other places of this class and from outside of this class.

Comment: Show us your code for `MySQLConnector`

Comment: In PHP, values have types, not variables.

Comment: PHP variables are universal-like typesets. E.g., they can be integers, strings, or references to a class. I haven't tried using `MySQLi` in an OO environment, but from my understanding of PHP, the code your using looks applicable. Otherwise, I'd suggest you use the data orientated method, and create your own `$this->query()` function.

Comment: _“The problem is: $this->connection isn't of mysqli type. It hasn't type.”_ – how did you come to that conclusion? Use `var_dump($this->connection)` in the following line, it’ll show you the type of the actual value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could, for example user **[PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)** instead of mysqli for its benefits. Or, you could simiply typecast like

```
public function setMysqli(mysqli $mysqli) {
    $this->mysqli = $mysqli;
}
```

A better way around would be to have those kind of stuff in the constructor as it is initialization:

```
class MySQLConnector implements DatabaseConnector {

    private $connection;

    /**
     * Initialize connector instance.
     * Not using OO API of mysqli here because it's junk anyways - you should use PDO.
     * @param $host The host of the SQL server.
     * @param $username The user for the database.
     * @param $password The password of the user.
     * @param $database The database to be used.
     * @throws RuntimeException if connection fails.
     */
    public function MySQLConnector($host, $username, $password, $database) {
        if (!$this->connection = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database)) {
            throw new RuntimeException(mysqli_connect_error());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve the connection reference for use.
     * The field $connection will always be a valid mysqli instance since
     * it is already initialized by the constructor.
     * @return A connection handle to the database for use with persistence operations.
     */
    public function getConnection() {
        return $this->connection;
    }

}
```